# Creating a cloud-function error alerting policy in GCP with terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, terraform

I am trying to make an alerting policy for error logs for cloud functions in GCP. I am having an issue from terraforming with the following logs.

```
AND severity>=ERROR": The lefthand side of each expression must be prefixed with one of {group, metadata, metric, project, resource}.
```

The tf code block I am using is this, the issue is using the severity>=ERROR section

```
resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "cloud_function_errors" {
      project               = var.project
      enabled               = var.alerts_enabled
      display_name          = "${var.cf_name}-errors"
      combiner              = "OR"
      conditions {
        display_name = "${var.cf_name}-errors"
        condition_threshold {
          filter     = "resource.type=\"cloud_function\" resource.labels.function_name=\"${var.cf_name}\"  resource.labels.project_id=${var.project} AND severity>=ERROR"
          duration   = "0s"
          comparison = "COMPARISON_GT"
        }
      }
      notification_channels = var.alerts_notification_channels
    }
```

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

Found the error, I was using the wrong block inside conditions

here is the correct tf block

```
resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "cloud_function_errors" {
  project      = var.project
  enabled      = var.alerts_enabled
  display_name = "${var.cf_name}-errors"
  combiner     = "OR"

  conditions {
    display_name = "${var.cf_name}-errors"
    condition_matched_log {
      filter = "resource.type=\"cloud_function\" resource.labels.function_name=\"${var.cf_name}\"  resource.labels.project_id=${var.project} AND severity>=ERROR"
    }
  }

  alert_strategy {
    auto_close = "604800s"
    notification_rate_limit {
      period = "3600s"
    }
  }
  notification_channels = var.alerts_notification_channels
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if you're using Cloud Functions (2nd gen) the Runtime logs will appear with the resource type cloud_run_revision. You can find more information on docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#using_the_logging_dashboard).

Here is the code for Cloud Functions (2nd gen):

```
resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "cloud_function_errors" {
  project      = var.project
  display_name = "${var.cf_name}-errors"
  combiner = "OR"

  documentation {
    content = "The $${resource.type} of $${resource.labels.service_name} in $${resource.project} has an incident."
  }

  conditions {
    display_name = "${var.cf_name}-errors"
    condition_matched_log {
      filter = "resource.type=\"cloud_run_revision\" resource.labels.service_name=\"${var.cf_name}\" severity>=ERROR"
    }
  }
    
  alert_strategy {
    notification_rate_limit {
      period = "3600s"
    }
  }
    
  notification_channels = var.alerts_notification_channels

  user_labels = {
    severity = "warning"
  }
}
```